# Function not firing correctly on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, logic

I have a function that makes two buttons. 
One button will auto scroll down and the other up.

It goes through an array and changes the button on every tap.

My problem is that I have to click the button twice to get it to work and then it does not get fired after that at all.

Is there a logic error in here I am not seeing?

What I want it the arrows to act like the twitter bootstrap image carousal. I want to click the arrows and have them take me to the next or previous section.

This is a screenshot of the the page and the arrows I am trying to change
IMG REMOVED

URL REMOVED

Sorry, I removed the img and url but with this site not being live yet, it shouldn't be viewed like that. I was in a pickle though.

I solved the problem. Read the comments if you have a similar one like this. 
Thanks everyone!

```
$(function () {
    var leftArrow = $('#left-arrow')
    var rightArrow = $('#right-arrow')




    rightArrow.bind("tap", rightTapHandler)
    function rightTapHandler(event){
        if (ai == 0) {
            alert('0' + event)
            ai = 1
            controllerContainer.innerHTML = linkArrayForwards[ai] + '<div id="right-arrow" class="arrow"></div></a>' + linkArrayForwards[0] + '<div id="left-arrow" class="arrow"></div></a>';
            return 
        } else if (ai > 0) {
            alert(ai)
            ai++
            controllerContainer.innerHTML = linkArrayForwards[ai] + '<div id="right-arrow" class="arrow"></div></a>' + linkArrayForwards[ai - 1] + '<div id="left-arrow" class="arrow"></div></a>';
            return                    
        } else if (ai >= linkArrayBackswards.length) {
            ai = linkArrayBackswards.length;
            controllerContainer.innerHTML = linkArrayForwards[ai] + '<div id="right-arrow" class="arrow"></div></a>' + linkArrayForwards[ai - 1] + '<div id="left-arrow" class="arrow"></div></a>';
            return 
        }  else {
            alert('nothin')
            return false
        }


    };
    leftArrow.bind("tap", leftTapHandler)
    function leftTapHandler(event) {
        if (ai == 0) {
            alert('0' + event)
            ai = 1
            controllerContainer.innerHTML = linkArrayBackswards[ai] + '<div id="right-arrow" class="arrow"></div></a>' + linkArrayBackswards[0] + '<div id="left-arrow" class="arrow"></div></a>';
            return 
        } else if (ai > 0) {
            alert(ai)
            ai--
            controllerContainer.innerHTML = linkArrayBackswards[ai] + '<div id="right-arrow" class="arrow"></div></a>' + linkArrayBackswards[ai - 1] + '<div id="left-arrow" class="arrow"></div></a>';
            return 
        } else if (ai >= linkArrayBackswards.length) {
            ai = linkArrayBackswards.length;
            controllerContainer.innerHTML = linkArrayBackswards[ai] + '<div id="right-arrow" class="arrow"></div></a>' + linkArrayBackswards[ai - 1] + '<div id="left-arrow" class="arrow"></div></a>';
            return 
        } else {
            return false
        }

    };
})
```

Comment: is there a reduced case scenario of this?

Comment: What do you mean by "a reduced case scenario of this"? I could try to bind but I am using jQuery mobile and the API says "jQuery( ".selector" ).on( "tap", function( event ) { ... } )"

Comment: It's just that, seeing a wall of code doesn't help anyone. Trying reducing your code down to just the things causing the issue and putting that in your question.

Comment: could you publish your actual code on jsfiddle?

Comment: I updated it a bit. I attached a screenshot and removed the arrays and some variables.

Comment: Yeah, I can give me second to set it up

Comment: jsfiddle would be a pain to set up. Here is the URL http://www.omega-9oils.com/plant-breeding/

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: what is the expected value for `ai`?

Comment: ai is an increment. I set the default value to 1

Answer (score 1):

From what i notised on your website, it alerts "0[option Option]" on the first click on any of the two arrows.

```
    if (ai == 0) {
        alert('0' + event)
        ai = 1
```

"ai == 0" must be true.. It's the only alert with "0" in it and the only reason it would pop that alert, as far as i know & see.

Apart from that, once you have clicked OK on the alert, the arrows seem to work perfectly fine for me..

**Edit**
Are you sure you are declaring ai before the "if (ai == 0)" check?
If you aren't. remove the alert so the code looks like this (for both arrows):

```
    if (ai == 0) {
        ai = 1
```

Comment: Yeah I modified a little to get that. But it does not do anything after that. It suppose to take you to section 3 after that and so forth.

Comment: I got it working though.... I ended up attaching onclick="function()" I wanted to use fancy jQuery and be "cool" but this works too